# Filtering data from mysql where a field is equal or great than X (Problem)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a new filter on my cannabis ecommerce site. I've prepared a range slider for filtering products with a selected amount of % CBD/THC but have no clue how to write a proper mysql query for such a conditions.

**I've got two tables:**

First is '*products*' where all items are being stored: id, product name, price, and so on

Second is '*custom_field_product*' where are attributes values such as cbd, thc are being stored

In this case I'd like to make a condition for:

> show product/s where custom_fields_product.product_id = product_id and custom_fields_product.product_filter_key = CBD and custom_fields_product.field_value is equal or greater than 10

[please see this screenshot - click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Huo7N.png)

Which should mean - Show only products where their CBD field value is equal or greater than 10

in HTML I've got two inputs: CBD Minimum which is $cbd_min, and CBD Maximum which is $cbd_max.

For now my code looks like this:

```
if ($cbd_min != "" && $cbd_min != 0) {
            $this->db->join('custom_fields_product', 'custom_fields_product.product_id = product.id');
            $this->db->where('product_filter_key', "cbd" <= $cbd_min);         }         
if ($cbd_max != "" && $cbd_max != 0) {
            $this->db->join('custom_fields_product', 'product.id = custom_fields_product.product_id');
            $this->db->where('product_filter_key', "cbd" >= $cbd_max);         }
```

and of course I get an error:

> Error Number: 1066
>
> Not unique table/alias: 'custom_fields_product'
>
> ```
> SELECT COUNT(\*) AS numrows 
> FROM products 
> JOIN users ON products.user_id = users.id
> JOIN custom_fields_product ON custom_fields_product.product_id = product.id
> JOIN custom_fields_product ON product.id = custom_fields_product.product_id
> WHERE users.banned = 0
>   AND products.status = 1
>   AND products.visibility = 1
>   AND products.is_draft = 0
>   AND products.is_deleted = 0
>   AND users.country_id = '175'
>   AND users.state_id = '2674'
>   AND products.category_id IN(15, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 14) 
>   AND product_filter_key = 1 AND product_filter_key = 0
> ```
>
> Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/system/database/DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 691

Maybe you have any ideas how to resolve this? Thanks in advance.

I've tried to resolve this by myself with typing queries such as where_in, select and so on, but I don't know how logically prepare this kind of code. I'm still learning programming.

Comment: As you can see there exists 2 `custom_fields_product` table copies in a query. And server does not know which table column should be used in any place. You must assign different aliases to these table copies, and use correct table alias for each column taken from one of these table copies. Finally you'd build something like `.. JOIN custom_fields_product AS t1 ON .. JOIN custom_fields_product AS t2 ON ..`

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, i'm curious did the error happens whenever you have `$cbdmin` and `$cbdmax` more than zero? if its within the use case, you should give both `custom_fields_product` aliases as Akina said. you can change your codeigniter join calls into something like: `->join('custom_fields_product as cfp_cbdmin', 'cfp_cbdmin.product_id = product.id')` for `cbdmin` one. the `cbdmax`, you should use different alias (e.g. `cfp_cbdmax`).

Comment: Guys, I've made some changes.


if ($cbd_min != "" && $cbd_min != 0 && $cbd_max != "" && $cbd_max != 0) {
$this->db->join('custom_fields_product', 'products.id = custom_fields_product.product_id AND custom_fields_product.product_filter_key = "cbd"');
}
 
if ($cbd_min != "" && $cbd_min != 0) {
$this->db->where('field_value' >= $cbd_min); 
}

if ($cbd_max != "" && $cbd_max != 0) {
$this->db->where('field_value' <= $cbd_max);
}


Now I got NO errors, but also NO results. What can be wrong?
Sorry I don't know how to style this code here..........

Answer (score 0):

Your quotes are wrong.

```
$this->db->where('custom_fields_product.field_value' >= $cbd_min);
```

should be

```
$this->db->where('custom_fields_product.field_value >= '.$cbd_min);
```

And even better is to (well, you should!) work with parameters, like

```
$this->db
    ->where('custom_fields_product.field_value >= ?')
    ->setParameters([$cbd_min]);
```